# One plus One ADB drives not getting installed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, adb, oneplusone

I am not able to install the ADB drivers/Oem drivers for my one plus one.

I have tried the following three methods given by the link and restarted my system

http://www.technobuzz.net/install-oneplus-one-usb-drivers-windows/

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have posted this much earlier

This was a bug in OPO android lollipop. Many devices(NOT on all ) were not able to connect to the windows using drivers. This was already fixed in marshmallow.

For more details refer:

http://www.idigitaltimes.com/downgrade-oneplus-one-cm12-cm11-fix-lollipop-bugs-manual-process-guide-437875